# Rails auto increment print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following piece of code which print the list of items in separated columns.

```
- if @product.type_id == 2
      %th.order_invoice_cell.each.count
        #{l(:item)}
      - @product.products.each do |p|
        %th.order_invoice_cell
          #{l(:item)}
```

But all the columns are named item, item, item. now if I want to have number mentioned like item1 item2 item3 and so on. how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, what your `#{l(:item)}` doing. but you can Use this:

```
- if @product.type_id == 2
      %th.order_invoice_cell.each.count
        #{l(:item)}
      - @product.products.each_with_index do |p, index|
        %th.order_invoice_cell
          = "item #{index + 1}"
```

It will give you item 1, item 2 and so on... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `each_with_index` instead. So you can do `@product.products.each_with_index do |p,index|`

Comment: can you please tell me how and where I can use it exactly in my code. coz i am new to haml ..

Comment: I have replaced the fourth line with that but its not working .